# Name of short story about girl surviving winter

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I read this story maybe ten years ago? It was in pioneer times (?) and a girl, her brother and father were going through a mountain pass to reach a town to sell their wares.

They went in the autumn, and her family was killed by some sort of accident. The young girl was unable to go any further, so the rest of the story was about her trying to survive the next few months there. She had two oxen with her, and end up having to kill one or both to eat, and converted the cart to a small house, etc. eventually in the spring she was found by some people coming through the pass again. I think at some point she might have also been attacked by wolves?

The majority of the story was about her surviving on her own, but I can’t remember all the details now. I think it was definitely a fictional short story, only a few pages long? Any ideas would be amazing!!!